# Connect multiple webcams with 1 USB hub

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to connect multiple(4 or more) webcams to one USB hub but failed with following warning codes:

```
[ WARN:0@20.273] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (464) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072875772
```

I tried all Opencv camera backends but also failed.
The results(indices where cam.read() returns True) are shown in code(in `if __name__=='main'`).

Here is my code:
(This is the code outputs the video being captured in real time, which can save captured images to folder with certain keyboard inputs.)

```
import cv2
import os
import time

def load_cams(cam_num, API:int=cv2.CAP_ANY):  # Camera loader
    cams = []
    cam_idx = []
    for i in range(cam_num):

        cams.append(cv2.VideoCapture(i+API))
        cams[i].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
        cams[i].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
        if cams[i].read()[0]:
            cam_idx.append(i)
            print("{}th camera .read(): ".format(i), cams[i].read()[0])
            print("{}tj camera .isOpened(): ".format(i), cams[i].isOpened())

    return cams, cam_idx


def API_test(cam_num, api_list):  # To test all backend APIs
    for idx, api in enumerate(api_list):
        if idx <= 2:
            continue
        print("API index: ", idx)
        cams, cam_idx = load_cams(cam_num, api)
        print(len(cam_idx))
        print(cam_idx)


def removeAllFile(filePath):  #
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        for file in os.scandir(filePath):
            os.remove(file)
        print("Removed All File")
    else:
        print("Can't remove files - Directory Not Found")


def save_from_cam(cam_num, path_save_capture, API=cv2.CAP_ANY):
    cams, cam_idx = load_cams(cam_num=cam_num, API=API)
    for idx in cam_idx:
        path_save = os.path.join(path_save_capture, str(idx))
        if not os.path.exists(path_save):
            os.makedirs(path_save)
        removeAllFile(path_save)

    print("Start camera")
    present_key = ord('n')
    count = 0
    while True:
        imgs = []

        # ckpoint_time = time.time()
        for idx in cam_idx:
            cams[idx].open(0)
            imgs.append(cams[idx].read()[1])
            # print('time lag:', time.time() - ckpoint_time)
            # ckpoint_time = time.time()

        for idx, img in zip(cam_idx, imgs):

            if idx not in cam_idx:
                continue
            if count == 0:
                print("open {}th camera".format(idx))
            cv2.imshow("{}".format(idx), img)

            if present_key == ord('n'):
                pass
            elif present_key == ord('y'):
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_save_capture, str(idx), "{}.png".format(count)), img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(10)
        count += 1

        if k == 27:  # ESC
            break
        elif k == ord('y'):
            present_key = k
            print('Start capturing')
        elif k == ord('n'):
            present_key = k
            print('End capturing')

    for cam in cams:
        cam.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__=='__main__':
    """
    Tested APIs (camnum is set to 10000)
    cv2.CAP_ANDROID = 1A000      : 0  [400]
    cv2.CAP_ANY = 0             : 1  [0, 3, 703, 1400]
    cv2.CAP_ARAVIS = 2100       : 2  []
    cv2.CAP_AVFOUNDATION = 1200 : 3  [200]
    cv2.CAP_CMU1394 = 300       : 4  [403, 1100]
    cv2.CAP_DC1394 = 300        : 5  [403, 1100]
    cv2.CAP_DSHOW = 700         : 6  [3, 700]
    cv2.CAP_FFMPEG = 1900       : 7  []
    cv2.CAP_FIREWARE = 300      : 8  [400, 403]
    cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE = 300      : 9  [400, 403]
    cv2.CAP_GIGNETIX = 1300    : 10 [100]
    cv2.CAP_GPHOTO2 = 1700      : 11 []
    cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER = 1800    : 12 []
    cv2.CAP_IEEE1394 = 300      : 13 [400, 403]
    cv2.CAP_IMAGES = 2000       : 14 []
    cv2.CAP_INTELPERC = 1500    : 15 []
    """

    api_list = [
        cv2.CAP_ANDROID,
        cv2.CAP_ANY,
        cv2.CAP_ARAVIS,
        cv2.CAP_AVFOUNDATION,
        cv2.CAP_CMU1394,
        cv2.CAP_DC1394,
        cv2.CAP_DSHOW,
        cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,
        cv2.CAP_FIREWARE,
        cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE,
        cv2.CAP_GIGANETIX,
        cv2.CAP_GPHOTO2,
        cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER,
        cv2.CAP_IEEE1394,
        cv2.CAP_IMAGES,
        cv2.CAP_INTELPERC,
    ]

    # API_test(cam_num=10000, api_list=api_list)

    save_from_cam(cam_num=1000, path_save_capture='./TestCapture', API=cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

My OS is window 10 and webcams are ABKO APC720 HD WEBCAM.

Comment: +)

- Webcams worked normally in the main camera app of Windows 10 (respectly). \\

- Webcams were recognized as normal in Windows Device Manager.

Comment: ++)-When a tested webcams in API_test (results in tested APIs), I connected 3 ABKO  720p webcams  in 1 usb hub.

Comment: +++)-If I connect multiple webcams to separate USB port in desktop directly, above code works.

Comment: they all have to share the bandwidth of the one controller. expect very poor video quality, or cameras not working at all, as seen here.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz where is "as seen here"

Comment: @Google you have a funny name, also "as seen here" meaning this question. what do you want?